# Tkinter widgets not displaying on using a loop

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a list result. I am trying to display the contents of result in label widget using tkinter. Only the first entry displays none other. I tries to debug, it looks like the loop runs throughout the length of the list but widgets are not displayed.

```
for i in range(0, len(result.deviceName)):

        position = 0.582 + (i * 0.5)
        print(result.deviceName[i])
        self.TLabel2_12 = ttk.Label(self.reportWindow)
        self.TLabel2_12.place(
            relx=0.044, rely=position, height=29, width=186)
        self.TLabel2_12.configure(text=result.deviceName[i])

        self.TButton1 = ttk.Button(
            self.reportWindow, command=lambda i=i: self.displayRoutes(i))
        self.TButton1.place(relx=0.366, rely=position,
                            height=25, width=136)
        self.TButton1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TButton1.configure(text='''VIEW ROUTES''')
        self.TButton1.configure(width=136)

        if(result.check[i] == 1):
            self.TLabel2_12 = ttk.Label(self.reportWindow)
            self.TLabel2_12.place(
                relx=0.198, rely=position, height=29, width=196)
            self.TLabel2_12.configure(text='''CORRECT''')

        else:
            self.TLabel2_12 = ttk.Label(self.reportWindow)
            self.TLabel2_12.place(
                relx=0.198, rely=position, height=29, width=196)
            self.TLabel2_12.configure(text='''INCORRECT''')


            self.TButton1_13 = ttk.Button(
                self.reportWindow, command=lambda i=i: self.displayError(i))
            self.TButton1_13.place(
                relx=0.512, rely=position, height=25, width=136)
            self.TButton1_13.configure(text='''ERROR''')
```

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include any imports and test data needed for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
self.reportWindow.update()
```

at the end of the loop to update the main root. That shows all of the widgets.